# How to apply drag behavior to a d3.svg.arc?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I apply d3.behavior.drag() to the following arc?

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(45 * (pi/180)) //converting from degs to radians
    .endAngle(3) //just radians

vis.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
```

I want to be able to drag the arc around. I have not been able to see anything that uses the drag behavior on any SVG path based object (only for basic elements like circle, rectangle, etc.)

The closest thing I can find related to dragging is this:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377

Though it appears that if you try to ".on("drag", dragmove) for the appended path (.append("path")) "d" comes out as undefined. And if you attach ".on("drag", dragmove)" to the arc itself, the event doesn't appear to fire...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag is a behaviour that you create and then apply to the elements you want to execute that behaviour. There should be no issue applying it to an arc.

So with your arc (minor modification to make the translation accessible):

```
var position = [200,200];

var arc = vis.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + position + ")");
```

Start by creating the behavior you want. Our drag will update the translation of the arc:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        position[0] += d3.event.dx;
        position[1] += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this)
        .attr("transform", function(d,i){
            return "translate(" + position + ")"
        })
    });
```

Now we attach the behaviour to the arc:

```
arc.call(drag);
```

You can try it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/tYKjn/).